# Hazelcast warnings in server logs everytime client disconnects

Tags: hazelcast

I am seeing below log statements every time the client disconnects. Anything we can do to avoid them as they doesn't seem to be really a warning?
I believe these should be at DEBUG level.

```
01/11/2017 14:14:38,465 - INFO [hz._hzInstance_1_FB_API.IO.thread-in-0][][com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection] [127.0.0.1]:31201 [FB_API] [3.6.2] Connection [Address[127.0.0.1]:59972] lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]
01/11/2017 14:14:38,466 - WARN [hz._hzInstance_1_FB_API.IO.thread-in-0][][com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingSocketReader] [127.0.0.1]:31201 [FB_API] [3.6.2] hz._hzInstance_1_FB_API.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[127.0.0.1]:59972, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
01/11/2017 14:14:38,467 - INFO [hz._hzInstance_1_FB_API.event-3][][com.hazelcast.client.ClientEndpointManager] [127.0.0.1]:31201 [FB_API] [3.6.2] Destroying ClientEndpoint{conn=Connection [0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:31201 -> /127.0.0.1:59972], endpoint=Address[127.0.0.1]:59972, alive=false, type=JAVA_CLIENT, principal='ClientPrincipal{uuid='7181902f-8fe9-4065-b610-5a0e9c4ad212', ownerUuid='7ff02f81-c0e3-4094-a968-507c7df4df9f'}', firstConnection=true, authenticated=true}
01/11/2017 14:14:38,467 - INFO [hz._hzInstance_1_FB_API.event-3][][com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionManagerService] [127.0.0.1]:31201 [FB_API] [3.6.2] Committing/rolling-back alive transactions of client, UUID: 7181902f-8fe9-4065-b610-5a0e9c4ad212
```

These exceptions/Errors are distracting our log analysis.

Comment: Are you able to use a newer version of Hazelcast than 3.6.2?

Comment: I think there's an issue for this already, let me see if I can find it

Comment: This ? https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/6035

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and have commented there to check if it was fixed in previous versions too. Unfortunately, our management has not agreed yet for upgrade. So we are still into 3.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a code issue. You have three choices:

1. Ignore it
2. Filter it out with logging, something like this for Log4j2:

`<Logger name="com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingSocketReader" level="error" additivity="false">`

(This is a bad idea, as you will miss genuine warnings)

3. Upgrade to 3.7, or 3.8 if this is GA when you do the upgrade